# Missing Web API Controller Class template for .NET CORE 2.0 in Visual Studio 2017, How do I get it?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to be able to see it listed when adding a new class like the following pic, but it doesn't list.  VS Community 2017 with .NET CORE 2.0 x64, and then I just did x86 ... big whiff still.  So frustrating when you just want to move along.  Please help :)

Problem:
[When searching for Web API Controller it doesn't exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8SpE.png)

What I Want:
[Web API Controller Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69CM8.png)

Comment: In ASP Core you have one type of controller: `Controller`
and this is kind of both MVC and Web API controller